# Pasting Dataframe in seperate excel files keeping all existing data in python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have 10 excel files with one sheet in each excel file:-
Sheet Name= Report Output 1

I have created dataframe based on 10 excel files by importing all 10 files through glob and pandas.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob(filename*.xlsx):
    info = pd.read_excel(f, sheetname='Report Output 1')
    df = df.append(info)
```

Did some filtration, merging and calculations as per the requirement.
Now I have one consolidated dataframe`final_df` which has data for 10 files after my calculations.

I want to paste the dataframe `final_df` back to all respective 10 files in New Sheet by splitting or groupby with unique value (column name `Source` in each file which has unique value) keeping original data in existing files(Sheet Name - Report Output 1) as it is.

I know `openpyxl` can perform this function through Python OpenPyXl `dataframe_to_rows` but how to write the code which will copy the dataframe to separate sheets.